# AWS Glue Transfer Data Frame to another Job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

Does anyone know if it is possible to transfer a Data Frame to another Job, as an argument, or even using another transfer option, with Boto3, etc?

For example:

Job1:

```
DF = spark.read.option("header", True).csv("s3://path")
##TODO - Send DF to another Job
```

Job2:

```
##TODO - Receives DF and performes a summary
DF.summary()
```

The Job2, will only take care of doing statistics, such as column counts, null counts, etc, but since it is a quite wide DataFrame (billions of rows), loading again in memory, takes a long time.

My current solution is to perform the "statistics" in the same job, but I'd like to do the same for multiples Jobs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you cannot pass it to another job. Have you tried writing this dataframe to a staging location and pass this path to another job?

Comment: Adding to a staging location won't help, because I would have to load it again from the staging location.
I guess it just cannot be done with Glue.